# Gemini Pro API's response omits the "text" field when I ask to translate a document

Tags: large-language-model, google-gemini

I integrate Gemini Pro into one of our internal tools to allow users to "ask" the documents in our database.

It all worked fine until I was conducting some tests today and noticed that the response objects simply omits the `text` field when I ask it to translate the document (originally in French) to English.

This came as a surprise to me, and searching in the API documentation, there's no mention of this procedure. Is this a bug or a feature and are there any sources to read more about this and how to mitigate against it?

Comment: To whoever voted to close - the question is valid, on topic, possibly encountered by others, and can be answered without opinions. While sample code or illustrative prompts would be helpful, it is possible to provide potential answers without these.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show the code or prompts you're using, so it is a bit difficult to guide you with details. However, there are a few things to look at that might provide hints at what caused a missing `text` field.

Check the [`finishReason`](https://ai.google.dev/api/rest/v1/GenerateContentResponse#finishreason) field for a candidate to see why it stopped producing output for that candidate.

Check the [`safetyRatings`](https://ai.google.dev/api/rest/v1/GenerateContentResponse#SafetyRating), both for the candidate and for the prompt to see if it was blocked for any of these reasons.